# Raid partitions not listed in /dev

Tags: linux, raid, partition

I've assembled software raid1 `/dev/md1`, and made two partitions `/dev/md1p1` and `/dev/md1p2`. Now even after reboot I can't see these two in `/dev`.

Why? (udev service is running)

```
#fdisk /dev/md1
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/md1: 2000.3 GB, 2000346808320 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 488365920 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/md1p1               1     9765625    39062498   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/md1p2         9765626   488365920  1914401180   8e  Linux LVM
```

---

```
# ls /dev/md1*
/dev/md1
```

---

```
# uname -a
Linux xen 2.6.26-2-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 14 10:19:53 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
# partprobe -s
Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/md1p1 -- Invalid argument.  This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/md1p1 until you reboot -- so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.
Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/md1p2 -- Invalid argument.  This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/md1p2 until you reboot -- so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.
Warning: The kernel was unable to re-read the partition table on /dev/md1 (Invalid argument).  This means Linux won't know anything about the modifications you made until you reboot.  You should reboot your computer before doing anything with /dev/md1.
```

Comment: @tdk2fe I've used cfdisk on md1

Comment: Are you able to successfully create a filesystem and mount it on those partitions?

Comment: @tdk2fe i can't mount them as they are not visible in `/dev`

Comment: does 'partprobe -s' show the md1 device?

Comment: @tdk2fe I've added partprobe output (machine was rebooted but errors remain)

Comment: What does /proc/mdstat say?